# Why are the coefficients in this proof multiplied by T?

Tags: proof-explanation, fourier-series, fourier-transform

[Online Proof of Fourier Transform](http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Fourier/Series/FTFS.html)

The link above shows the full proof of the Fourier Transform using the limiting case of the Fourier Series. I don't understand why this was done in the proof however:

> $$ x(t) = \sum\limits_{n =  - \infty }^{ + \infty } {{c_n}{e^{jn{\omega _o}t}}} $$  $$ c_n = {1 \over T}\int_T {x(t){e^{ - jn\omega_0t}}dt} $$ $$ T{c_n} = \int_T {x(t){e^{ - jn\omega_0t}}dt}  $$
>
> As $T \rightarrow \infty$ the fundamental frequency, $\omega_0=2\pi/T$, becomes extremely small and
>   the quantity $n\omega_0$ becomes a continuous quantity that can take on any
>   value (since $n$ has a range of $\pm \infty$) so we define a new variable ω=nω0;
>   we also let $X(\omega)=Tc_n$. Making these substitutions in the previous
>   equation yields the analysis equation for the Fourier Transform (also
>   called the Forward Fourier Transform).
>
> $$
> X(\omega ) = \int\limits_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {x(t){e^{ - j\omega t}}dt}
> $$

Wouldn't multiplying coefficients by T, result in the Fourier Transform being scaled by T according to the proof? If so, the Fourier transform does not accurately describe the 'amount' of frequencies in a function as they too are scaled by T.

Comment: This is too cumbersome. You should *at least* copy and past those parts here.

Comment: Let $X_T(\omega) = \int_{-T/2}^{T/2} x(t) e^{-i \omega t}dt$ then the goal is to make the Riemann sums of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty X(\omega) e^{i \omega t} d\omega = \lim_{T \to \infty}\int_{-T}^T X_T(\omega) e^{i \omega t} d\omega $ appear using that for $|t| < T/2$ then $x(t) = \frac{1}{T} \sum_k X_T(2\pi k/T) e^{2i \pi k t/T}$. The main difficulty is that in general the latter integral and series don't converge absolutely at least when $x(-T/2) \ne x(T/2)$, which is also why we usually prove the Fourier series and Fourier transform inversion theorems separately